# Why is the landing area of an aircraft carrier angled to port side, not starboard?

Tags: aircraft-carrier

On a modern aircraft carrier, [the landing area is not aligned with the axis of the ship](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flight_deck#Angled_flight_deck).

Given this part of the ship needs to be asymmetric, why do most (if not all) angled flight decks point to the left side of the ship (and not the right)? Is there any advantage to favor this side?

Comment: I think it allows them to launch and land aircraft at the same time. By having them land a different direction than launch (they launch off the front I believe (in line with the ship)) a go around remains possible. I am not 100% sure of this so I will let someone with more knowledge weigh in.

Comment: @Dave - That's pretty much it. The angled deck also allows for additional catapults (which, because they cross the landing area, are only used during an emergency "scramble") but this is secondary to maintaining the ability to bolter.

Comment: The comments and answers do not answer the question which is "why port?".  The OP knows why it's angled, just not why the superstructure is on the starboard side.

Comment: @Simon You are right. I've updated my answer.

Comment: I'm guessing here.  For side-by-side multi crew ops, the captain (sitting on the left) has a clear view of the traffic pattern on the approach and for a bolter and also has the LSOs, paddles etc on that side (and it's natural for a clear view to have them on the other side to the island).

Comment: Is this question asking why decks are angled to the left, or why superstructures are on the right? While partially related, those are two separate questions and there appears to be confusion about which is the actual question.

Comment: Related questions: Why are the numbers 3, 6, 9 right of the 2, 5, 8 on each and every numpad? And why does a clock's hand rotate clockwise?

Comment: I wonder when the first answer will relate the sidedness of the carrier with the spinning direction of props in the time when the convention was started. This is the only reason I can think of which would explain the issue - all other apply equally for both sides.

Comment: @PeterKämpf It could also just have started out as something that made sense for the particular ships that first had angled decks (which were converted to angled decks, not first built with them), and then been kept that way in later designs because there's no real reason to not do that.

Comment: @Peter Kämpf: I think propeller spinning direction is actually the answer. Because of the spinning direction, left turns are generally easier in propeller aircraft; this is ultimately why we have the convention that the pilot-in-command sits in the left seat, and why traffic patterns at uncontrolled airports generally go counterclockwise. The latter convention seems like a plausible reason to put the superstructure on the starboard side, which then leads to the landing area angled towards port.

Comment: It seems the best answer today is from Mark. A study was conducted, the results were taken into account for the choice.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Farhan's answer covered why the deck is angled in the first place. As far as why the landing area of the deck points left instead of right, this is for several reasons:

- Angling to port makes the most use of the deck area behind the catapults. Angling starboard would require the catapults to be shifted left off the centerline of the carrier (yes, the carrier does have two additional catapults on the port side, but these can't be used while the carrier is retrieving aircraft, which is more often than you'd think as the carrier maintains regular patrols).
- Angling the landing strip toward the "island" (conning tower) of the carrier just doesn't sound like a good idea when you say it. That goes double when you realize the carrier is underway while you're trying to land on it, and therefore you have to lead the landing strip a little. If you don't, you'll end up "behind" the ship and the landing strip. With the landing strip angled to port, a plane on a "lagging" approach (lined up "behind" where the carrier's going to be at touchdown) will have a relatively clear path off to port for a wave-off. Angled to starboard, a plane that's "lagging" the carrier would be pointed right at the tower.
- It would be possible to mirror the entire deck layout; island to port, landing area angled starboard. The reason the island is on the starboard side is primarily convention; all U.S. Navy aircraft carriers ever built have been either flush-decked or have had the island to the right. That's thus a familiar sight picture for naval pilots across all eras, and easy to train to. A new carrier design doesn't get the luxury of a whole new crew trained an entirely different way; the Navy's been training pilots since 1910, they've been landing planes on boats since 1927, and they'll do it they way they've been doing it for 88 years, thank you very much.

  The Imperial Japanese Navy commissioned two carriers, *Akagi* and *Hiryu*, with island-left designs, fielded with the idea that the island-left carrier would sail in formation with an island-right carrier in the same flag group, with opposing traffic patterns that didn't conflict. This procedure never materialized in practice; most carrier groups in both Japanese and U.S. fleets ended up with a single carrier due to their high cost and lower total number, a pattern that continues today, and even when two (or more) carriers were close enough to be called part of the same naval group, they typically maintained a wide enough spacing to permit a left-hand pattern for both ships.

Comment: I think the third bullet point actually answers the question. The entire answer, though, is well written and informative.

Comment: I would generally agree with point number 3, but points 1 and 2 are inaccurate.  The port catapults, known as the waist cats, are used all the time and cat 4 is actually the only cat on centerline in the Nimitz class. Also, the carrier is *always* underway during launch and recovery.  You also never lead the deck, you should only reference the deck for lineup.  I'm not sure what you mean by a lagging approach, but if you grossly overshoot the centerline during the approach turn you'll get waved off on the starboard side of the ship, the same would hold true if the decks were reversed.

Comment: The 3rd point by itself answer the question. But why do the US Navy decide to built the island on the right? Why does this convention still influence the carrier design several decades latter?

Comment: Wild guess here, but in an emergency it is probably easier for a pilot to identify a rough approach angle of all carriers are built the same. After all, the ship might have turn round in the time you where away from it.

Comment: @ManuH Remember, at no point was there a clean break in carrier design. New designs always enter service alongside existing designs; also, pilots on the new carriers were trained on the old ones. So, keeping consistency with other ships currently in service will mean this sort of decision will last *way* past when the ships where it was established leave service.

Comment: @cpast The biggest point is consistency.  Naval Aviation, as an institution, is generally opposed to change, because consistency breeds perfection.  Every approach, regardless of location, should be flown exactly the same as it would be at the ship, and the ground track should be painstakingly accurate with each pass to breed muscle memory, proper sight picture, and perfection.  We'll keep flying this pattern until the last Aviator gets fired.

Answer (score 27):

Why is the deck of an aircraft carrier angled to the left?  Because the island is on the right.

Why is the island on the right?  Because studies on the [HMS *Furious*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HMS_Furious_(47)) showed that [pilots tended to turn left](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HMS_Eagle_(1918)#Construction_and_conversion) during an aborted landing.

Comment: Why this answer is not the selected one?? It goes directly to the subject and clarifies that the choice wasn't arbitrary, out of habit only.

Comment: This is the correct answer. HMS Hermes was the follow-up carrier to the HMS Furious and the first with an island, and was originally designed with **two** islands, later revised to one on the starboard side because of the experience with pilots turning left after an aborted landing, and to give increased width to the flight deck. The following is the reference given from the HMS Hermes Wikipedia article, and is a very good book on the subject. Friedman, Norman (1988). British Carrier Aviation: The Evolution of the Ships and Their Aircraft. Annapolis, Maryland: Naval Institute Press

Answer (score 9):

The innovation of the angled flight decks gives several key advantages:

Most notably, it is far safer for carriers to land aircraft on angled decks that point away from the superstructure, ground personal and aircraft parked forward.  This greatly reduces mishaps involving aircraft crashing into people and objects on the deck.  *The reason the landing area is canted to the left is because the superstructure is on the right.  For clarification, the superstructure is always on the right.  The carrier landing pattern has remained constant for decades so that every approach to the carrier will remain as constant as possible.*

Edit: To take it a step further, when the decision was first made to place the superstructure on the right side it was likely because the carrier pattern was already a left hand pattern.  Its worth noting that the standard traffic pattern is a left pattern as well, and a superstructure on the left side, during a left hand pattern, would partially obscure the landing area from view during the downwind and approach turn.

Comment: Wikipedia cites a book from the Naval Institute Press that traces the decision to put the island of HMS *Hermes* (the first carrier with an island) on the starboard side in part to the fact that pilots already preferred to turn to port on a missed approach.

Comment: @cpast well, there you go, naval aviation doesn't like change and the pattern has been the same forever

Answer (score 5):

<strike>The answer lies in the same [article section you referenced](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flight_deck#Angled_flight_deck). There are two animations there, on the right.</strike>

[image: Animation]

As you can see in this animation, the longer runway is for landing. If an aircraft could not stop, it needs to take off again. That is the reason aircraft carriers have the landing strip angled so that it will not interfere with aircraft which are about to take off or the parked ones.

[Simon clarifies](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/15087/why-is-the-flight-deck-of-an-aircraft-carrier-heading-to-port#comment35064_15087) that OP is specifically asking about why landing runways are not pointed towards the right/starboard side.

[While the island](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aircraft_carrier#Flight_deck)<sup>1</sup> is usually built on the starboard side of the fight deck, the Japanese aircraft carriers Akagi and Hiryū had their islands built on the port side.

The reason might be more of a tradition that reasons behind it. Please note that there very few aircraft carriers in the world, and only a few countries have it. So there is not a big competition or difference of standards in this area.

---

<sup>1</sup>: The superstructure of a carrier (such as the bridge, flight control tower) are concentrated in a relatively small area called an island

Comment: And if the cable snaps then the plane ends up besides the ship instead of under where it can destroy the propeller (pilot will eject either way)

Comment: This doesn't answer the question asked.

Comment: Why all the crossed-out text? If it's not supposed to be there, delete it. If it is supposed to be there, let me read it.

Comment: @DavidRicherby I think it's better to keep this crossed-out text as some comments refered to it (and it is made to be readable).

Comment: @ManuH Comments that refer to deleted parts of an answer should just be flagged as obsolete. Otherwise, things just get too confusing.

Comment: @DavidRicherby I think this usage of [crossed-out text](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strikethrough) has already been discussed [multiple times](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234606/strike-through-or-edit) on [meta.stackexchange.com](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184410/should-i-edit-my-wrong-answer-or-post-a-new-answer/184411#184411) The good way for Farhan should have been to delete this answer and re answer the question

Comment: I found this answer useful as a reminder of the basics of carrier operations, like where the cats are.  And for the fully top-down view making it easier to visualize that a plane has to deal with as they come in to land.

Answer (score 2):

Prop planes used to (and still do today!) drift  to the side opposite to the propeller rotation direction during take-off. And while it's true that the first carriers were flat-decked (no island, no banking) many pilots begin their training with prop planes.And there were some crazy 50's turboprop carrier operated planes like the A-1 in times immemorial when jets were not quite established as the future of sea-borne aviation.
One might be forgiven to assume that the first "island" carrier designs originating back then had something to do with allowing a quick take-off with the rudder straight compensating for the drift by angling the deck. And as the layout was proven and found good...Just my two cents.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Aviation.SE! do you have any reference for your assertions?

Comment: you have posted no link :/ (also, consider putting any source you might have in your answer, not in a comment)

Comment: sorry, I'm new to this...[link] (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ur18PF-6hIc) at 17:38 please observe the F6F Hellcat ,although launched on a catapult, still shows heavy left banking (being heavy ,all filled up with ammo and fuel etc while accelerating). Aircraft were launched in waves at the time, and it was not uncommon to have multiple launch and landing events simultaneously. Imagine that of all those aircraft- the ones that took off  were subjected to unintentional heavy left banking, while the ones that landed -with engines close to idle- were not so much.

Comment: @Federico OP said drift opposite propeller rotation.  It is more than just an assertion when you state the cause.

Comment: @Blam doesn't change the fact that it does not provide any reference.

Comment: @Federico So? No other answer has a reference. Does it need a reference to "prop", "drift", and "opposite" to be valid. Your comment has no reference to reference.  Really does it need  reference to basic physics?

Answer (score 1):

**Why always the port side?**  There's no technical reason so it can only be convention - for example several carriers operating together could steam in the same direction and launch their aircraft in the same direction too.  The aircraft would be on (approximately) parallel paths so would not have to take special action to avoid each other.

It also occurred to me that the bridge would be always on the right/starboard, docking facilities might be arranged to take advantage of this...

[HMS Hermes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HMS_Hermes_%2895%29) was apparently the first carrier with the "control tower" (Island) to starboard.  This may be the origin of the convention.  The link states that pilots prefer a port turn on an aborted landing...

Comment: The technical reason is that the deck is angled away from the superstructure which is always on the right. This greatly reduces mishaps.

Comment: But why is the superstructure always on the right?  This is what the original question is all about.  One of the comments by @Simon seems to give the only possible reason so far (it **may** favour the left-seat pilot)

Answer (score 1):

At this point in time it's because all carriers in commission have their islands to starboard, so all carriers will *continue* to have their islands to starboard. From a naval engineering standpoint there's no reason to prefer having the island to starboard vs. port, but from a pilot training standpoint it's important to minimize the differences between carriers in order to minimize pilot confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Another factor:  Consistency.  Pilots might have to land on something other than their home carrier.  Carrier landings are already very exacting flying, learning one pattern is better than learning two.